# How can I convert two methods into a single method to increase efficiency?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, refactoring

How can I convert two methods into a single method to increase efficiency and make clear and concise code?

I have three more conditions like this to check but I did not mention (that's too long):

```
 public void getmembershipstatusmembers()
 {
        if (cbGEStatustype.Text != "")
        {
            var totalmembers = from tsgentity in eclipse.members
                               join memtomships in eclipse.membertomships on tsgentity.member_Id equals memtomships.member_Id
                               join mshipoptiions in eclipse.mshipoptions on memtomships.mshipOption_Id equals mshipoptiions.mshipOption_Id
                               join mshiptypes in eclipse.mshiptypes on mshipoptiions.mshipType_Id equals mshiptypes.mshipType_Id
                               join mshipstatus in eclipse.mshipstatustypes on memtomships.mshipStatusType_Id equals mshipstatus.mshipStatusType_Id
                               where mshipstatus.mshipStatusType_Name.StartsWith(cbGEStatustype.Text)
                               select new
                               {
                                   tsgentity.member_Id,
                                   tsgentity.member_Lastname,
                                   tsgentity.member_Firstname,
                                   tsgentity.member_Postcode,
                                   tsgentity.member_Reference,
                                   tsgentity.member_CardNum,
                                   tsgentity.member_IsBiometric,
                                   tsgentity.member_Dob,
                                   mshiptypes.mshipType_Name,
                                   mshipstatus.mshipStatusType_Name,
                                   memtomships.memberToMship_EndDate
                               };
            dgvReportMembers.DataSource = totalmembers;       
        }
    }
    public void getcardnumbers()
    {
        if (txtcardnum.Text != "")
        {
            var totalmembers = from tsgentity in eclipse.members
                               join memtomships in eclipse.membertomships on tsgentity.member_Id equals memtomships.member_Id
                               join mshipoptiions in eclipse.mshipoptions on memtomships.mshipOption_Id equals mshipoptiions.mshipOption_Id
                               join mshiptypes in eclipse.mshiptypes on mshipoptiions.mshipType_Id equals mshiptypes.mshipType_Id
                               join mshipstatus in eclipse.mshipstatustypes on memtomships.mshipStatusType_Id equals mshipstatus.mshipStatusType_Id
                               where tsgentity.member_CardNum.StartsWith(txtcardnum.Text)
                               select new
                               {
                                   tsgentity.member_Id,
                                   tsgentity.member_Lastname,
                                   tsgentity.member_Firstname,
                                   tsgentity.member_Postcode,
                                   tsgentity.member_Reference,
                                   tsgentity.member_CardNum,
                                   tsgentity.member_IsBiometric,
                                   tsgentity.member_Dob,
                                   mshiptypes.mshipType_Name,
                                   mshipstatus.mshipStatusType_Name,
                                   memtomships.memberToMship_EndDate
                               };
            dgvReportMembers.DataSource = totalmembers;
        }

    }
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
 private void allmembers()
 {
       var members = from ......
                          .......
                          .......
        if (cbGEStatustype.Text != "")
        {
           dgvreports.datasource = members.where(.......)
         }
         if (txtcardnum.Text != "")
         {    
             dgvreports.datasource = members.where(.......)
         }
    }
```

Comment: Why doesn't what you pasted at the bottom work? What error is produced, or what limits you from doing that?

Comment: Code does not get more clear and concise by stuffing everything into one single method. Not more efficient either.

Comment: @SpikeX i have tried bottom ones that only limited to members table checking and i have included another three tables in join condition ... i am not able to check other tables , suppose like this  "cbGEStatustype.Text" this is from mshipstatustype table.....i am not able to check this one with mshipstatustype name field in table....

Comment: What about skipping the where condition in the individual functions, but only have it in the if condition as you've already suggested? Or didn't I understand your question fully?

Comment: @albin   code is very clear, when ever the user enter in  textbox (txtcard) i want to retrive the member details those who have that card num.. and same thing with membership also ...

Comment: @Markus thats what i am saying i am not able to check the mshipstatus name in if condition .....

Comment: Yeah, at this point combining the code into a single method doesn't do a whole lot for you. If you're having this much trouble combining this code, you shouldn't be doing it. If you don't like the code, find another way to refactor it. Merging methods is not the solution, though.

Comment: @spikeX would you pls suggest any alternative method to do , i do have any idea.....

Comment: That's outside the scope of the question. And please don't submit another one, StackOverflow is not for "How do I make this better?" questions, it's for specific questions that have specific, concrete answers. You'll just have to figure it out or ask somewhere else, sorry.

Comment: I think this has already been said, but you need to do the exact opposite. Break long methods into smaller concise functions that perform specific tasks. This leads to clearer, more maintainable, and more testable code. It has no specific impact on performance, it's just good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, I would think you could create your method so that instead of directly setting the data source to the results of the query, it returns the results as an IQueryable object so that you can apply as many subsequent filters as you need to.   The difficulty, I think might be that your two method seem to be using an anonymous type which won't be communicable amongst methods, but you could create a simple type definition to fill the void.

For example

```
public class Foo {
public string MemberID { get; set;}
public string LastName { get; set;}
// ... etc.
} 

public IQueryably<Foo> GetUnfiltereredSource()
{
    // NOTE: No WHERE here...
    return 
        from tsgentity in eclipse.members 
        join memtomships in eclipse.membertomships on tsgentity.member_Id equals memtomships.member_Id 
        join mshipoptiions in eclipse.mshipoptions on memtomships.mshipOption_Id equals mshipoptiions.mshipOption_Id 
        join mshiptypes in eclipse.mshiptypes on mshipoptiions.mshipType_Id equals mshiptypes.mshipType_Id 
        join mshipstatus in eclipse.mshipstatustypes on memtomships.mshipStatusType_Id equals mshipstatus.mshipStatusType_Id 
        select new Foo
        { 
           MemberID =  tsgentity.member_Id, 
           LastName = tsgentity.member_Lastname, 
           // ... etc.
        }; 
}

public void DoStuff()
{
    dgvreports.datasource = GetUnfilteredSource().Where(x => x.MemberCardNumber.StartsWith(...));

    // OR

    dgvreports.datasource = GetUnfilteredSource().Where(x => x.MemberShipStatusType.StartsWith(...));

    // etc..
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are barking up the wrong tree.  Making one method do the job of two other methods is sometimes a good idea, but will never make your code measurably more (or less) efficient.

Will the suggested change make your code more clear?  That's worth doing.  Will it reduce duplication?  That's worth doing, too.  Is it the right change to make?  Looking at your code, I would guess that a better approach would be to extract the common parts of your methods into a new method, and call that new method from your existing methods.

Comment: I am looking for same thing ,avoiding duplication how can i do that ...would you pls give any sample code ....

Comment: Your two blocks of code look identical, except for replacing `cbGEStatustype.Text` with `txtcardnum.Text`.  So if you had a method that took the text as a parameter, you could call that method with either `cbGEStatustype.Text` or `txtcardnum.Text`.  Is that clear?

Comment: txtcardnum.text is comparing data with cardnum of member  table and cbgestatustype is comparing data with mshipstatus type table ..how it will be the same????